# phonegap app using handlebars.js (list view) not registering touch on iOS

Tags: ios, handlebars.js, phonegap

i am building an app using phonegap, handlebars.js (for templating). I have a js list where i iterate though to show information of each element of the list using handlebars.js templates. there is a click event registered for each element of the list.

```
    ######### javascript code #####################
    $('body').on('click', 'div.payment_tab', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if(self.allowclick==1) {
                    document.location=$(this).attr("data-target");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    console.log("else for clicking the payment tab. allowclick is not 1");
                    return false;
                }
            });

    $('body').on('click' , 'div.payment-checkbox', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).toggleClass('checked');
                $(this).toggleClass('unchecked');
                $(this).parent().find('.invoice_amount').toggleClass('added');
                $(this).parent().find('.invoice_amount').toggleClass('notadded');

                var amounts = $('div.payment-amount-status .added');
                var total = 0.00;

                amounts.each(function(key,value) {
                    if($(value).text() != "") {
                        total += parseFloat($(value).text());
                    }
                });

                $('#amount_to_pay').text(total.toFixed(2));


            });
     ######swipe event javascript######
$("#invoicesView").swipe( {

            swipeStatus:function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
            {
                    if (phase=="start")
                    {
                        app.allowclick=0;
                    }
                    if (phase=="cancel")
                    {
                        app.allowclick=1;
                    }

            },

            swipeDown:function(event, direction, distance, duration)
            {
                //Only Let swipe, if the Element is at the very top of the scroll
                if($("#invoicesView .contentholder").scrollTop()<=40 && distance>40 )
                {
                    app.allowclick=0;
                    app.get_payment_details();
                }

            },
            swipeRight:function(event, direction, distance, duration)
            {


            },

            swipeLeft:function(event, direction, distance, duration)
            {

            },

            threshold:50,
            cancelThreshold:50,
            allowPageScroll:"vertical"
          });

    ###### part of the main.html (handlebars.js template)############################
     <script id="invoices-li-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            {{#.}}
            <li>
            <div class="payment-checkbox checked"></div>
            <div class="payment_tab" data-target="#invoices/{{{this.payment_id}}}">
            <div class='payment_info'>
                <p>ORDER #: 
                    <span class="invoice-info-order">{{this.order_num}}</span>
                </p>
                <p>PO: 
                {{#if this.customer_po}}
                <span class="invoice-info-po">{{this.customer_po}}</span></p>
                {{else}}
                <span class="invoice-info-po">N/A</span>
                {{/if}}
                <p>DATE:
                    <span class="invoice-info-date">{{this.createdtime}}</span>
                </p>

            </div>
            <div class='payment-amount-status {{this.paid}}'>
                <p><span class ='invoice-amount-label'>TOTAL:</span>$<span class='invoice_amount added'>{{this.amount}}</span></p>
                <p><span class ='invoice-status-label'>STATUS:</span><span>{{this.paid}}</span></p>
                <p class='payment_id'>{{this.payment_id}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class='clearfix'></div>
            </div>
            </li>
            {{/.}}
            </script>
```

In the bundled app, the click event works fine on android but does not work on iOS (version 10,tested on iphone 6+). Even the checkbox click(div.payment-checkbox) is not registered on ios. Below is the config.xml i am using for the app. **note that we have a similar list view in the app where the click event works on ios.**

```
######## config.xml #########################      
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget android-versionCode="xxx" id="xxxxxxx" ios-CFBundleVersion="3.0.1" version="3.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" >
        <name>xxxxx</name>
        <description>
           xxxxxx
        </description>
        <author email="xxx@xxxxx.com" href="xxxxxx">
           xxxxxxxx
        </author>
        <content src="index.html" />
        <preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0" />
        <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
        <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
        <preference name="target-device" value="handset" />
        <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
        <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
        <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
        <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
        <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
        <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
        <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
        <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
        <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" />
        <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
        <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm"  />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm"  />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm"  />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm"  />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" source="npm">
        <param name="URL_SCHEME" value="xxxxx" />
        </gap:plugin>
        <feature name="SplashScreen">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen"/>
            <param name="onload" value="true" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="SplashScreen">
            <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="InAppBrowser">
          <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
        </feature>
        <feature name="Device">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
        </feature>

        <icon src="icon.png" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/xxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi" />

        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180"  />

        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />

        <!-- Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />

        <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />

        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />

        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />

        <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" gap:platform="ios" width="50" height="50" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="100" height="100" />

        <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/android_ldpi_portrait.png" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/android_mdpi_portrait.png" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/android_hdpi_portrait.png" />
        <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/android_xhdpi_portrait.png" />

        <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
        <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
        <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
        <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen/ios/Default@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="960" height="1440" />
        <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
        <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-portrait-ipad.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
        <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-landscape-ipad.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

        <!-- Retina iPad -->
        <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
        <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />

        <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />

        <platform name="ios">
        <gap:plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push"  spec="1.5.3" source="npm">
            <params>
            <param name="SENDER_ID" value="xxxxxxxx" />
            </params>
        </gap:plugin>
        </platform>

        <platform name="android">
        <gap:plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push"  spec="1.7.2" source="npm">
            <params>
            <param name="SENDER_ID" value="xxxxxxx" />
            </params>
        </gap:plugin>
        </platform>
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
        <access origin="*" />
        <access origin="http://*" />
        <access origin="https://*" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
        <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
        <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
        <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
        <platform name="android">
            <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="ios">
            <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
            <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        </platform>

        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
        <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
        <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
        <access origin="*"/>
    </widget>
```